# Folding pandas time series into single day

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have a time series of events that spans multiple days-I'm mostly interested in counts/10min interval. So currently, after resampling, it looks like this

```
2018-02-27 16:20:00    5
2018-02-27 16:30:00    4
2018-02-27 16:40:00    0
2018-02-27 16:50:00    0
2018-02-27 17:00:00    0
...
2018-06-19 05:30:00    0
2018-06-19 05:40:00    0
2018-06-19 05:50:00    1
```

How can I "fold" this data over to have just one "day" of data, with the counts added up? So it would look something like this

```
00:00:00    0
00:10:00    0
...
11:00:00   47
11:10:00   36
11:20:00   12
...
23:40:00    1
23:50:00    0
```

Comment: So, do you want to ignore days and simply get counts over 10 mins interval?

Comment: @HarvIpan I think so? Combine the counts for each 10 min interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your series index is a DatetimeIndex, you can use the attribute `time` -- if it's a DataFrame and your datetimes are a column, you can use `.dt.time`.  For example:

```
In [19]: times = pd.date_range("2018-02-27 16:20:00", "2018-06-19 05:50:00", freq="10 min")
    ...: ser = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 6, len(times)), index=times)
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [20]: ser.head()
Out[20]: 
2018-02-27 16:20:00    0
2018-02-27 16:30:00    1
2018-02-27 16:40:00    4
2018-02-27 16:50:00    5
2018-02-27 17:00:00    0
Freq: 10T, dtype: int32

In [21]: out = ser.groupby(ser.index.time).sum()

In [22]: out.head()
Out[22]: 
00:00:00    285
00:10:00    293
00:20:00    258
00:30:00    263
00:40:00    307
dtype: int32

In [23]: out.tail()
Out[23]: 
23:10:00    280
23:20:00    291
23:30:00    236
23:40:00    303
23:50:00    299
dtype: int32
```

Comment: This seems to give me the right time series. I need to look into it further though because its giving me constant counts for each time slot. Edit: Just kidding, I was using .count() instead of .sum().

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want a sum of values per 10 min intervals in the first time column. You can perhaps try something like:

```
df.groupby('columns')['value'].agg(['count'])
```